# returning subarray in single sql response

Tags: php, sql, laravel

In laravel right now, I have a pretty simple function that returns a query result through an ajax call

```
$sql = "
    SELECT  
        itemID,
        itemTime,
        t2.itemCommentType,
        t2.itemCOmment
    FROM ITEM T1
    INNER JOIN COMMENTS T2
    ON T1.itemID = t2.itemID";

try {
    return DB::connection('mysql')->select($sql);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return false;
}
```

This works fine but it returns two rows because of the comment type, where the id and time are the same for both

```
itemID   |   itemTime   |   itemCommentType   |   itemComment
--------------------------------------------------------------
123         09-11-2019      Title                   Testing
123         09-11-2019      Comment                 New Comment
```

How should I alter my code (not the query) to return only one object with one ID and Time, but create an array of each comment type?

I want only a single result but I need to be able to show the title and comments in different areas on the web page

Comment: Why aren't you using a model? Why don't you just do `LIMIT 1` or `->first()`?

Comment: I don't want to limit because I need both. The inner join returns multiple because a single item can have multiple comments and comment types and I need them all in the returned object

Answer (score 0):

Use Model. In Item model-

```
public function itemComents(){
    return $this->hasMany('ItemComment::class', 'itemId');
}
```

And get your result-

```
Item::with('itemComments')->find(123);
```

To get all item with comments

```
Item::with('itemComments')
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should group by ItemId and itemTime columns like this:

```
DB::connection('mysql')->select($sql)->where('itemID',$id)->groupBy('itemID','itemTime')->first()
```

Comment: That will still give me two results though

Comment: try to group just with itemID column